# getHostByAddr for .htaccess-Files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, host

I have problems with spam from servers with the domain `.kimsufi.com` and `.SteepHost.Net`. I used to block them using the following htaccess-command:

```
Deny from .SteepHost.Net
Deny from .kimsufi.com
```

Instead of blocking requests, I'd like to redirect them to a static page (e.g. "access.html" saying "please contact the admin,...") For IP-addresses this works with the following commands:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ###.###.75.51
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ access.html
```

But how can I use the users' host instead of the IP-address? I tried for example:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^(.*)\.kimsufi\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^(.*)\.SteepHost\.Net$ [NC]
```

But it did not work,...

Comment: Try not requiring a subdomain, by using: `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^(.*\.)?kimsufi\.com$ [NC,OR]`

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace %{REMOTE_ADDR} by %{REMOTE_HOST}. But it implies to set [HostnameLookups](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#hostnamelookups) to On (or Double), which can slow down your site.

Answer (score 1):

Just use REMOTE_HOST instead of REMOTE_ADDR.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^.+\.EvilDomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ access.html
```

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html